# CountAsync() does not work even if the query returns an IQueryable<T>?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a query in c#:

```cs
var queryResult = query.Include(x => x.Activity).Include(x => x.Commission).Include(x => x.People)
  .GroupBy(x => new { x.PeopleId, x.DateReference })
  .Select(x => new RegistrationDateGrouppedViewModel()
    {
       DateReference = x.Key.DateReference,
       PeopleId = x.Key.PeopleId,
       MinuteWorkedSum = x.ToList().Sum(min => min.MinuteWorked),
       RegistrationList = x.ToList().ToRegistrationViewModel().ToList()
    }); // the type of this query is IQueryable<RegistrationDateGrouppedViewModel>
```

Inspecting the query it returns this:

[image]

**RegistrationDateGrouppedViewModel.cs**:

```cs
public class RegistrationDateGrouppedViewModel
{
  public DateTime DateReference { get; set; }
  public Guid PeopleId { get; set; }
  public int MinuteWorkedSum { get; set; }
  public List<RegistrationViewModel> RegistrationList { get; set; }
}
```

I want to enable pagination on my query so i added it:

```cs
var result = new PageResult<RegistrationDateGrouppedViewModel>()
{
  CollectionSize = await queryResult.CountAsync(), // this is of type int
  Result = queryResult.Paginate(page, size).ToList() //this is of type List<T>
};
```

This is the pagination method:

**PagingExtension.cs**:

```cs
public static IQueryable<TSource> Paginate<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> data, int page, int size)
{
   if (page > 0 && size > 0)
   {
      return data.Skip((page - 1) * size).Take(size);
   }
   return data;
}
```

But inside the variable `result` particularly the `CountAsync()` method returns `null`.

Why even if i give him the correct type is not counting my `result○6` and returns `null`?

Can anyone help me on this one?

### UPDATE

**PageResult.cs**:

```cs
public class PageResult<T>
{
   public List<T> Result { get; set; }
   public int CollectionSize { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What will happen if you just do `var count = await queryResult.CountAsync()` will it give you the count?

Comment: It's says the same thing: `null` and automatically goes on the return statemente as if like is breaking the code

Comment: is your function has async modifier and calling code uses await on it?

Comment: What function? Do you mean query? If yes query is equal to `var query = context.Registration.AsQueryable()`

Comment: The function that `var result = new PageResult.....` it must have async modifier and calling code must have await when calling it. Please add a full code of the function (with it's definition) which does `var result = new PageResult...`

Comment: Updated the question, `var result = ...` is after the `queryResult`, i can't post the whole function tho.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well it turns out that i just needed to add this:

```cs
var result = new PageResult<RegistrationDateGrouppedViewModel>()
{
   CollectionSize = queryResult.ToList().Count(), // added ToList() here
   Result = queryResult.Paginate(page, size).ToList()
};
```

Before counting i had to make the query a list using `.ToList()` and now pagination works as expected!
Thanks @simplygood for providing help

Comment: That's bad. This will fetch everything into memory and perform count on it. At least paginate on the resulted list, don't do a second query. But correct way to handle this - fix the original query so the `Count` works.

Comment: I still believe that your method where this code is executed doesn't have async modifier and is not returning Task<PageResult...>

Comment: @simplygood it is returning this: `public async Task<PageResult<RegistrationDateGrouppedViewModel>> GetRegistrationListGroupedByDateAsync(RegistrationFilterViewModel filters, int page, int size)`

Comment: @simplygood and then in my controller: `var result = await _registrationService.GetRegistrationListGroupedByDateAsync(filters, page, size);`